# Oracle installation requires old rpm versions, what to do?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, installation

I am installing Oracle 11g R2 on OEL6.

I run the following command, for to check only prerequisites

```
./runInstaller -silent -responseFile /0/grid/response/crs_install_mk.rsp -executePrereqs
```

It generated a log that contains the following info:

```
INFO: Package: libaio-0.3.105: This is a prerequisite condition to test whether the package "libaio-0.3.105" is available on the system.
INFO: Severity:IGNORABLE
INFO: OverallStatus:VERIFICATION_FAILED
INFO: -----------------------------------------------
INFO: Verification Result for Node:testr1n1
INFO: Expected Value:libaio-0.3.105 (i386)
INFO: Actual Value:missing
INFO: Error Message:PRVF-7532 : Package "libaio-0.3.105 (i386)" is missing on node "testr1n1"
INFO: Cause: A required package is either not installed or, if the package is a kernel module, is not loaded on the specified node.
INFO: Action: Ensure that the required package is installed and available.
```

Whan I check this package:

```
rpm -qa|grep libaio

libaio-0.3.107-10.el6.x86_64
libaio-devel-0.3.107-10.el6.x86_64
libaio-devel-0.3.107-10.el6.i686
libaio-0.3.107-10.el6.i686
```

And when I try to install

```
rpm -Uvh libaio-0.3.105-2.i386.rpm

warning: libaio-0.3.105-2.i386.rpm: Header V3 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 73307de6: NOKEY
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
        package libaio-0.3.107-10.el6.x86_64 (which is newer than libaio-0.3.105-2.i386) is already installed
        package libaio-0.3.107-10.el6.i686 (which is newer than libaio-0.3.105-2.i386) is already installed
```

What should I do now? I have newer version than Oracle requires. Ignore it?

Comment: The most probably you can ignore it. But aren't you trying to install 11.2.0.1? Get 11.2.0.4 instead. I did not see such errors with this version.

Comment: Ok, I will ignore it. I am trying to install old version and then upgrade it to 11.2.0.3

Comment: Install 11.2.0.3 and save yourself from upgrade. As you probably know 11.2.0.x is full install and unlike 10.2 series you can install 11.2.0.x from the start.

Answer (score 2):

Packages that can be ignored:

```
libaio-0.3.105 (i386)
compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3 (i386)
libaio-devel-0.3.105 (i386)
libgcc-3.4.6 (i386)
libstdc++-3.4.6 (i386)
unixODBC-2.2.11 (i386)
unixODBC-devel-2.2.11 (i386)
pdksh-5.2.14
```